# Does JanusGraph run on Windows 10

Tags: batch-processing, hadoop2, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm running on Windows 10 with [janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2](https://docs.janusgraph.org/changelog/).

I have put the `winutils.exe` in the `bin` folder.

```java
    P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\bin>gremlin-server.bat
    Error: Could not find or load main class Files
```

I had a quick look at the bat script and added some echo statements:

```bash
    echo "%1"
    
    IF "%1" == "-i" ( 
        GOTO install
    ) else (
        GOTO server
    )
    
    :: Start the Gremlin Server
    
    :server
    
    IF "%1" == "" (
      SET GREMLIN_SERVER_YAML=%JANUSGRAPH_HOME%\conf\gremlin-server\gremlin-server.yaml
    ) ELSE (
      SET GREMLIN_SERVER_YAML=%1
    )
    
    java %JAVA_OPTIONS% %JAVA_ARGS% -cp %CP% org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer %GREMLIN_SERVER_YAML%
    
    echo %JAVA_OPTIONS%
    echo %JAVA_ARGS%
    echo %CP%
    echo %GREMLIN_SERVER_YAML%
    echo "call to GremlinServer"
```

The output:

```java
    P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\bin>gremlin-server.bat
    .;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar;;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-all-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-berkeleyje-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-bigtable-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-cassandra-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-cql-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-es-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-hadoop-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-hbase-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-lucene-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-solr-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\*;
    ""
    Error: Could not find or load main class Files
    -Xms32m -Xmx512m  -Djanusgraph.logdir=P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\log  -Dtinkerpop.ext=P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\ext  -Dlogback.configurationFile=conf\logback.xml  -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\conf\gremlin-server\log4j-server.properties  -Dlog4j.debug=true  -Dgremlin.log4j.level=WARN  -javaagent:P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar  -Dgremlin.io.kryoShimService=org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoShimService
    ECHO is off.
    .;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar;;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-all-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-berkeleyje-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-bigtable-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-cassandra-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-cql-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-es-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-hadoop-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-hbase-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-lucene-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\janusgraph-solr-0.2.0.jar;P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\lib\*;
    P:\Software\DB\NoSQL\janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2\conf\gremlin-server\gremlin-server.yaml
    "call to GremlinServer"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question was also asked on the [janusgraph-users](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/janusgraph-users/uAHgB-p8OT4/WxVKufjBAgAJ) Google Group, and I've copied my answers here:

> JanusGraph does run on Windows 10. The user experience is not ideal,
>   and could use some help with people with Windows expertise. I've
>   opened up [issue
>   950](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/950) to track
>   making the prepackaged distribution more Windows-friendly.
>
> Your problem is probably coming from your `CLASSPATH` variable, and
>   I'd think that `".;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip;"` is messing it up because of the
>   spaces in the path. Try unsetting the `CLASSPATH` before running
>   `gremlin-server.bat`.
>
> The default Gremlin Server configuration uses
>   `janusgraph-cassandra-es-server.properties` because the pre-packaged
>   distribution `bin/janusgraph.sh start` will start a single node
>   Cassandra, a single node Elasticsearch, and the Gremlin Server. If you
>   want to run with Cassandra, you could go a version directly from the
>   Apache Cassandra site or a Datastax distribution if you want to go
>   with an MSI installer. If you're not interested in using Cassandra,
>   you could change the `gremlin-server.yaml` to use the
>   `janusgraph-berkeleyje-server.properties` which is pretty good for
>   getting started.