# JanusGraph Server Failed To Start With Bash

Tags: sh, git-bash, janusgraph, gremlin-server, tcpportsharing

## Problem

Why does [`janusgraph-server.sh start`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/) server fails to start? 
Running [`git BASH`](https://gitforwindows.org/) and [JanusGraph:latest [Version 0.6.3 (February 18, 2023)]](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases).

### Setup

1. [Download JanusGraph package `janusgraph-x.x.x.zip`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases)
2. [Install JanusGraph `unzip janusgraph-x.x.x.zip`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/)
3. Download and Install [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)
4. Open [Git-Bash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash)
5. Navigate to JanusGraph-Installation directory
6. Execute `bin/janusgraph-server.sh start`

## Result

### Expected

JanusGraph-Server to start.

### Actually

JanusGraph-Server doesn't start or put out any error message.

```bash
$ bin/janusgraph-server.sh start
/.../Janusgraph/janusgraph-0.6.3/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml will be used to start JanusGraph Server in background
Server failed
```

## Tried

### Checking if the run directory was wrong

```bash
$ cd bin 
$ sh janusgraph-server.sh start
/.../Janusgraph/janusgraph-0.6.3/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml will be used to start JanusGraph Server in background
Server failed
```

### Checking if the command was wrong

```bash
janusgraph-server.sh
Usage: janusgraph-server.sh {start [conf file]|stop|restart [conf file]|status|console|config [conf file]|usage <group> <artifact> <version>|<conf file>}

    start           Start the server in the background. Configuration file can be specified as a second argument
                    or as JANUSGRAPH_YAML environment variable. If configuration file is not specified
                    or has invalid path than JanusGraph server will try to use the default configuration file
                    at relative location conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml
    stop            Stop the server
    restart         Stop and start the server. To use previously used configuration it should be specified again
                    as described in "start" command
    status          Check if the server is running
    console         Start the server in the foreground. Same rules are applied for configurations as described
                    in "start" command
    config          Print out internal script variable to debug config
    usage           Print out this help message

In case command is not specified and the configuration is specified as the first argument, JanusGraph Server will be started in the foreground using the specified configuration (same as with "console" command).
```

### Checking if the port was available

```bash
$ netstat -ano | findstr "8182"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8182         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       24528
```

[LISTENING](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22946/what-sense-can-be-made-out-of-time-wait-close-wait-established) got me worried but found that 
[TCP-Ports can have multiple programs listening to the same socket, just not bind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8824852/11705601). 
Which is good because I have another IntelliJ programming that needs to be running and uses that port for its `java.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kelvin Lawrence! 
JanusGraph can't run on Windows due to the way filepaths are handled.

```bash
bin/janusgraph-server.sh: line 211: C:\Program: No such file or directory
janusgraph-server.sh: line 211: C:\Program: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Line 211 is where Java gets invoked to actually launch the JanusGraph server. It looks like paths (or similar) are getting confused between Windows and the linux Git terminal perhaps. There is a gremlin-server.bat shipped with Janus - that might work better.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285036/does-janusgraph-run-on-windows-10